# CKEditor slow styling issue

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

When I refresh the node add/edit form page which has some elements having CKEditor enabled, there is a delay in applying the style of CKEditor on the text edit form element. I mean it shows the transition from the basic view into the CKEditor styled view.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you change ur jquery version ? Are you using a minify module ?

Comment: I use simplify next to it to remove the drupal text formatting box below the text editor element.

Comment: I don't think simplify is the problem. But try to disablr and clear caches and see what happend.